# Symfony 2 loosing session inside an iFrame

Tags: php, symfony, iframe

I'm trying to add a hosted payment solution to an old Symfony 2.6 project. This is the standard hosted solution where you embed Payment Gateway's form inside an iframe, to allow user to securely submit their CC information. When payment is processed Payment Gateway redirects the user back to my site using GET request and sends me the payment token as GET param.

This all happens inside the iFrame obviously and this whole process works fine, except for the last step.

When user is redirected back to my callback URL inside the iframe, Symfony for some reason doesn't recognize user's session and redirects user to the login. I get message: `security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token` in the log. That happens only for that one call, user remains logged in on the rest of the site. User logins are controlled by fos_userbundle, in the standard setup.

Callback URL looks like this: `http://some.site/foo?paymentToken=12345`, and if I enter that url directly into the browser it works just fine. Even when I set iframe's src directly to that url it loads fine. But when user is 302 redirect-ed back to that url from the payment gateway it fails (using Chrome browser).

Payment gateway is using https, my site is using regular http, so I guess it has something to do with switching the security levels? But have no idea how to solve it.

Since the redirect comes from the 3rd party server I can't control the headers or anything else about that request.

UPDATE: I've noticed that Chrome sends the header: `upgrade-insecure-requests:1`, not sure if it's causing the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that this is not a Symfony problem, but an issue with how Chrome handles redirects from secure to insecure sites (possibly a bug?).

Chrome doesn't send any cookies on 302 redirect from https to http page, and that's why user is not recognized properly. Everything works fine with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This can be also you're testing the app in app_dev.php (developing mode) and the iframe is calling the production verision (app.php). Each application manage different sessions.